# Cannot fix error Types of parameters 'r' and 'a' are incompatible

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I try to replicate this code from [this blog](https://ybogomolov.me/higher-kinded-data/), but running into some pretty obscure errors

```
import { option, identity, apply } from 'fp-ts';
import type { Kind, URIS } from 'fp-ts/HKT';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';

type OrderId = string;

type OrderState = 'active' | 'deleted';

interface User {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly isActive: boolean;
}

interface OrderHKD<F extends URIS> {
    readonly id: Kind<F, OrderId>;
    readonly issuer: Kind<F, User>;
    readonly date: Kind<F, Date>;
    readonly comment: Kind<F, string>;
    readonly state: Kind<F, OrderState>;
}

type Order = OrderHKD<identity.URI>;
type OrderOption = OrderHKD<option.URI>;

const validateOrder = (inputOrder: OrderOption): option.Option<Order> =>
  pipe(inputOrder, apply.sequenceS(option.Apply));
//                 ^
//                 | here
// Argument of type '<NER extends Record<string, Option<any>>>(r: EnforceNonEmptyRecord<NER>) => Option<{ [K in keyof NER]: [NER[K]] extends [Option<infer A>] ? A : never; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: OrderOption) => Option<{ [x: string]: any; }>'.
//  Types of parameters 'r' and 'a' are incompatible.
//    Type 'OrderOption' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, Option<any>>'.
//      Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'OrderHKD<"Option">'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how this code could have worked, since the result of `sequenceS` has a constraint `<NER extends Record<string, Kind<F, any>>>`, which cannot be met by an interface due to possible declaration merging (see [this TypeScript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41518#issuecomment-726371178), for example). And that constraint was already present in 2019, which is way before the blog post was written.

Anyhow, you can get the example to work by declaring `OrderHKD` as a `type` rather than an `interface`:

```
type OrderHKD<F extends URIS> = {
    readonly id: Kind<F, OrderId>;
    readonly issuer: Kind<F, User>;
    readonly date: Kind<F, Date>;
    readonly comment: Kind<F, string>;
    readonly state: Kind<F, OrderState>;
}
```